# Using Dictionaries, For-Loops and Brackets in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, brackets

I need help creating a dictionary. The purpose of the dictionary is to calculate the size of a tax credit. There are eight schedules, and each has three brackets. You choose the schedule based on the filing status and number of qualifying children. In the first bracket, the credit is phased in as a percentage of earned income. In the second bracket, the credit maxes out. In the third bracket, the credit begins phasing out as a percentage of earned income. The problem is that I am not sure how I should structure the calculator to produce those results, or if this is even possible. I suspect there would need to be three if statements, one for each bracket. Here is what I have so far:

```
#import TaxReturn class
from TaxReturn import TaxReturn

#create brackets for phasein rates and phaseout rates for the earned income tax credit (EITC)
class EITC:
   def __init__(self, taxReturn):     
       self.brackets = {
           "single" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 0 : ((0, .0765), (6480, .0765), (8110, .0765)),
           "single" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 1 : ((0, .34), (9720, .34), (17830, .1598)),
           "single" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 2 : ((0, .40), (13650, .40), (17830, .2106)),
           "single" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children > 2 : ((0, .45), (13650, .45), (17830, .2106)),
           "married_jointly" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 0 : ((0, .0765), (6480, .0765), (13540, .0765)),
           "married_jointly" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 1 : ((0, .34), (9720, .34), (23260, .1598)),
           "married_jointly" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children == 2 : ((0, .40), (13650, .40), (23260, .2106)),
           "married_jointly" and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children > 2 : ((0, .45), (13650, .45), (23260, .2106))
       }

#calculate EITC credit
   def CalcEITC (self, taxReturn):
      eitc_credit = 0
      for bracket in reversed(self.brackets[taxReturn.taxComp.filing_status and taxReturn.eic_qualify_children]):
          if taxReturn.taxPayments.earned_inc > bracket[0]:
              eitc_credit += (taxReturn.taxPayments.earned_inc - bracket[0]) * bracket[1]
              taxReturn.taxPayments.earned_inc -= taxReturn.taxPayments.earned_inc - bracket[0]
```

Comment: You will get better answers if you describe your problem more accurately. For example, what is the structure of "taxReturn"? What also catches my eyes is that the "self.brackets" variable is declared as a dict, but the way you define it does not work at all! You need to define a set of keys, and assign values to them. A priori I would not solve your problem using a dict, but again, you should specify it more accurately.

Comment: @Christophe Hi there. How would you suggest I solve my problem? I was trying to avoid using a series of "if" statements. Tax Return is structured as a series data from tax returns. So I am passing in earned income, the filing status, and the number of children from this class.

Comment: Sorry I cannot really help... Maybe someone else does? For me I think you need to clearly define the inputs, the output and the calculation that takes place in the middle.

Comment: @Christophe. Sure, I'll try to be clearer. The input is earned income, taxReturn.taxPayments.earned_inc and the desired output is the eitc_credit. The code in the middle calculates the size of the credit by multiplying the rate times the earned income amount.